# How do you get Matlab mapreduce to use the key passed from the map function

Tags: matlab, mapreduce

Here is a sample reduce function from the Matlab documentation:

```
function MeanDistReduceFun(intermKey, intermValIter, outKVStore)
    sumLen = [0 0];
    while hasnext(intermValIter)
        sumLen = sumLen + getnext(intermValIter);
    end
    add(outKVStore, 'Mean', sumLen(1)/sumLen(2));
end
```

This creates a final dataset tagged by the key `Mean`. However, I would like to dynamically generate the key based off the unique keys from the `map` stage. Can I simply use `intermKey` in place of `'Mean'` in the `add` function, or should I include the key in `intermValIter` somehow and extract it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short answer:** Yes, you can use `intermKey` to use the unique keys passed by the map function.

**The long answer:** Between the map and reduce stages, all of the unique keys and their associated values are stored as `ValueIterator` objects:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/valueiterator-object.html

Each `ValueIterator` object is associated with a single key. So once this intermediate grouping is done, the reduce function is called a single time for each unique key passed by the mapper, and `intermValIter` contains all of the values associated with the unique key `intermKey`. Therefore, specifying `intermKey` will use each of the unique keys passed by the mapper.

As the above doc link mentions, the only interaction you have with the `ValueIterator` object is by using `hasnext` and `getnext` to loop through the values contained in `intermValIter`.